# View generation and reserved names in PHP

Tags: php, include, scope, unset

This is a bit of a peculiar one; I don't think this is in fact possible, however the **SO** community has surprised me time and time again; so here goes.

Given in PHP; I have the following snippet:

```
$path = 'path/to/file.php';
$buffer = call_user_func(function() use($path){
    ob_start();
    require $path;
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

When included, `path/to/file.php` will have `$path` in it's scope. *Is there any way to prevent this variable from being available in the context of the included file?*

For instance, given `unset()` returned the value of the variable it was unsetting, I could do:

```
require unset($path);
```

But of course that doesn't work.

---

For those curious, I'm trying to prevent `$path` from inheriting a value from the include-*er*.

"Security-by-obfuscation" is a consideration I made; passing something like `$thisIsThePathToTheFileAndNobodyBetterUseThisName`, but that seems a bit silly and still isn't foolproof.

For other "reserved" variables that *should* be inherited, I've already went with `extract()` and `unset()`:

```
$buffer = call_user_func(function() use($path, $collection){
    extract($collection);
    unset($collection);
    ob_start();
    // ...
```

---

### Edit:

What I finally went with:

```
$buffer = call_user_func(function() use(&$data, $registry){
    extract($registry, EXTR_SKIP);
    unset($registry);
    ob_start();
    // only $data and anything in $registry (but not $registry) are available
    require func_get_arg(0);
    return ob_get_clean();
}, $viewPath);
```

Perhaps my question was a bit misleading, through my use of `use()` to pass variables into the anonymous function scope; passing arguments was an option I neglected to mention.

Regarding @hakre and `use()` + `func_get_args()`:

```
$var = 'foo';
$func = function() use($var){
    var_dump(func_get_args());
};
$func(1, 2, 3);

/* produces
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`func_get_arg()`](http://php.net/func_get_arg) instead of using traditional function arguments:

```
$buffer = call_user_func(function() {
    ob_start();
    require func_get_arg(0);
    return ob_get_clean();
}, $path);
```

Comment: Simple and elegant, I knew there would be a way using core functions. Thanks @Andrew Moore.

Comment: @hakre - Doesn't, but `use()` wasn't a requisite; I sort of neglected to mention that, check my edit.

Comment: @TomcatExodus: Well that makes it obviously trivial.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the help of an additional function. In the example I used echo instead of require:

```
$path = 'hello';

function valStore($value = null) {
    static $s = null;
    if ($value !== null)
        $s = $value;
    else
        return $s;
}

valStore($path);
unset($path); # and gone
echo valStore();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
$path = 'path/to/file.php';
function getPath() {
    global $path;
    $p = $path;
    unset($path);
    return $p;
}
$buffer = call_user_func(function() {
    ob_start();
    require getPath();
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Berk Demirkir - So from what I'm gathering between the approach you and @hakre took, the only way is to define a function to store/fetch the value. Darn, my global scope was so clean too. Defining one for this one-off will be like painting an orange streak down an otherwise white wall.

Comment: @hakre: Sorry `use` keyword is for closures. Copy/paste mistake. Corrected

Comment: @Berk: Why not just `require $GLOBALS['path'];`?

Comment: @hakre: It's just my personal preference. I don't like using $GLOBALS. Generally i don't use globals :)

Comment: @Berk: I meant not generally but in the suggestion you just make: Why create a function to access a global variable?

Comment: @hakre & Berk - In my haste I also neglected to mention that this process is occurring in a method; the purpose for `call_user_func()` is only to escape from the method's scope, thus preventing the passing of `$this` into the required file. `$GLOBALS` would not have been an option, and I also would have needed to either define the function outside the method, or do a `function_exists()` everytime.

Comment: @TomcatExodus: That affects global then.