# How to make variables available in the template?

Tags: php, templates

I have the following class:

```
abstract class TheView
{
  public $template = NULL;
  public $variables = array();

  public function set($name, $value)
  {
    $this->variables[$name] = $value;
  }
  public function display()
  {
    include($this->template);
  }
}
```

The template file is a simple PHP file:

```
<?php
echo $Message;
?>
```

How can I make all the variables in `TheView::$variables` available in the template (the key of each item should be the name of the variable).

I've already tried to add all variables to `$GLOBALS` but that didn't work (and I think it's a bad idea).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always end up doing this:

```
public function render($path, Array $data = array()){
    return call_user_func(function() use($data){
        extract($data, EXTR_SKIP);
        ob_start();
        include func_get_arg(0);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }, $path);
}
```

Note the anonymous function and `func_get_arg()` call; I use them to prevent `$this` and other variable "pollution" from being passed into the template. You can unset `$data` before the inclusion too.

If you want `$this` available though, just `extract()` and `include()` directly from the method.

So you can:

```
$data = array('message' => 'hello world');
$html = $view->render('path/to/view.php', $data);
```

With *`path/to/view.php`*:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want the View object passed, but not from the scope of the `render()` method, alter it as follows:

```
public function render($path, Array $data = array()){
    return call_user_func(function($view) use($data){
        extract($data, EXTR_SKIP);
        ob_start();
        include func_get_arg(1);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }, $this, $path);
}
```

`$view` will be the instance of the View object. It will be available in the template, but will expose only public members, as it is from outside the scope of the `render()` method (*preserving encapsulation of private/protected members*)

Comment: I see a **-1**; curious as to why? What would you do differently, mystery **-1**'er?

Comment: Hmmm I don't see a -1, maybe he/she changed his opinion ;)

Comment: @user897029 - Must have; I invite -1s, if followed by constructive and *useable* criticism. I had received a -1 on another answer that used the same approach, shortly before or after as well. Meh.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract):

```
public function display()
{
    extract($this->variables);
    include($this->template);
}
```

Comment: Works also fine, thanks! But I think, it'll be cleaner if I just include the view variables not $this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($variables as $key => $value){
  $$key = $value;
}
```

Comment: That's the same as `extract($variables, EXTR_OVERWRITE);`.

Comment: Ahh, okay! I don't know all the nice little features of PHP yet.

Comment: I heard of `extract()` but I didn't find out the solution for (now solved) my problem. That's a programmers life - always learning by doing ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function to import variables from an array into the current symbol table.

```
abstract class TheView
{
  public $template = NULL;
  public $variables = array();

  public function set($name, $value)
  {
    $this->variables[$name] = $value;
  }
  public function display()
  {
    extract($this->variables);
    include($this->template);
  }
}
```