# Splitting an array into the variables in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, split

I have this array, $display_vars, and I want to split it into separate variables, so each variable's name is the array key, and it's value is the value, so to speak. So if the array was like this:

```
$display_vars = array(
'title' => 'something',
'header' => 'something else'
);
```

Then I want to end up with the equivalent of this:

```
$title = 'something';
$header = 'something else';
```

Can you think of any way I can possibly do this?

Comment: Here's also a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8376780/897029

Answer (score 15):

The [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function does exactly this.

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/EYd7R)** (includes bonus reference to `get_defined_vars`).

Answer (score 8):

[`extract()`](http://php.net/extract)

Be mindful about overwriting variables of the same name in the current scope. Read up on the second parameter if this is a concern.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
extract($display_vars);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use just access it using the same array ? Calling a function like **`extract`** is just an overload.

```
<?php
$display_vars = array(
'title' => 'something',
'header' => 'something else'
);

echo $display_vars['title']; //something
echo $display_vars['header']; //something else
```