# Process multiple select field as single variables in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, get

I have a  field in my HTML form that accepts exactly 7 selections (End User is picking seven pictures out of about 20) and need to pass the selection into PHP as separate variables.

My HTML form element:

```
  <select name="pics[]" multiple="multiple">
  <option value='101'>Picture 1</option>
  <option value='102'>Picture 2</option>
           ...
  <option value='120'>Picture 20</option>
  </select>
```

On the PHP end, I need to have each of the 7 options the user selected stored in separate variables, for ex:

```
   $a = 101; $b= 103; etc
```

I know I can list them using a foreach loop, but how can I separate them into individual variables?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about using [arrays](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) instead? "but how can I separate them into individual variables" --- any particular reason for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting an array into the variables in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420103/splitting-an-array-into-the-variables-in-php)

Comment: @koala_dev: assuming it will be `$pics['101']` - `exctract()` won't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your example literally (exactly 7 variables named from `$a` to `$g`):

```
list( $a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g ) = $_POST['pics'];
```

You now have 7 variables, each holding one selected value.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.